# ">" not working to direct output of python command to file

Tags: python, linux, bash, macos, python-2.7

I have decided to try [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/) to help with a refactoring to check the imports. It keeps dumping output on the screen and ">" does not send it to a file, it just creates an empty file.

I had to unfortunately create a virtualenv with Python 2.7 as it probably does not work properly in Python 3. Still, it can probably check a Python 2 project, even though it is written in Python 2. Am using a Mac, but it seems to use similar commands to Linux on the command line.

I did

```
pip install six
pip install graphviz
pip install snakefood
```

once the Python 2 environment was activated.

Then if I type

```
$ sfood-checker path/to/folder
```

..it dumps a huge amount of text on the screen, but

```
$ sfood-checker path/to/folder > check.txt
```

..only creates an empty file. Any idea what is wrong, how to fix it? Would like to carefully go through the file in sublime.

Comment: Probably because the messages are printed to `std_err` instead of `std_out`. Btw, this is more of a bash/unix question than python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are redirecting `stdout`, but your program is writing to `stderr`.  The fix is to redirect `stderr`:

```
$ sfood-checker path/to/folder 2> check.txt
```

Or redirect *both* `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
$ sfood-checker path/to/folder &> check.txt
```

Background: when processes are initially created, they generally *always* have three initial file descriptors already opened for them:

- `0`, stdin, "Standard Input", a read-only stream
- `1`, stdout, "Standard Output", a write-only stream
- `2`, stderr, "Standard Error", a write-only stream

There is precisely zero difference between `stdout` and `stderr`, other than convention and the file descriptor number.  By convention, then, status messages and other "informational" content is output to stderr (some version of `fwrite(stderr, informational_data);`, and the data required for normal operations of the program are written to stdout.

Comment: Thanks that worked which is the main thing, but why would they write a package which outputs to `stderr` when it's not an error message?

Comment: The syntax `cmd &> file` is a non-standards compliant bash extension.  Some shells will actually follow the standard and run cmd in the background followed by a second command (a no-op) which truncates the file.  Better to write `cmd > file 2>&1`

Comment: @WilliamPursell you are of course pedantically not wrong.  Good point.

Comment: @cardamom Some programs that expect their output to be parsed further will chose to write everything that is not part of their expected output to `stderr` even if it is not an error message. Things like reporting input parameters back.

Comment: @Arne thanks that clarifies it, the snakefood author chose to do it that way. Possibly it is also Mac versus Linux behaviour.. "some shells"